# Minitest stub_any_instance and methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, stubs

If I do

```
Klass.stub_any_instance(:new, raise(RuntimeError) do
  ...
end
```

the RuntimeError is raised at the stub_any_instance line and not, as I would like, later when a Klass.new() occurs.

Is there a way to make this work the way I would like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `raise` in a lambda:

```
Klass.stub :new, -> { raise(RuntimeError) } do
  assert_raise { Klass.new }
end
```

(You'll also want to use `stub` rather than `stub_any_instance`.)